# Weird left margin appears if using a listview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview

I use listviews to display lists of elements on the pages of my aspx website.
Now every time i use a listview a left margin of 37px left to the elements in the listview appears even tough i don't use one. If i display an element without the listview this doesn't appear, but when i put that div that contains the element in a listview it appears.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlData1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
     </LayoutTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <div id="artmic">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ></asp:HyperLink>                         
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Is this a bug? Does anyone know how i could fix this?

Comment: do you use css'? do you have a default theme?

Comment: Try to use FireBug or IE Developer Tools to see where this style comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a beginners problem.
I just needed to add `margin-left:-37px;`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a CSS issue, and it could be a browser default value.  Try adding a *temporary* style with the cover-all reset:

```
* {margin:0; padding:0}
```

If you then re-view the page, hopefully the unwanted margin will disappear.  You can then apply a generic ul style to your main stylesheet, or add a class/id to the `<ul>` tag and style this appropriately.